# How can I detect if my shell script is running through a pipe?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

How do I detect from within a shell script if its standard output is being sent to a terminal or if it's piped to another process?

The case in point: I'd like to add escape codes to colorize output, but only when run interactively, but not when piped, similar to what `ls --color` does.

Comment: Here are some more interesting test cases!


<a href="http://serverfault.com/questions/156470/testing-for-a-script-that-is-waiting-on-stdin">Testing for a script that is waiting on stdin</a>

Comment: @user940324 The correct link is http://serverfault.com/q/156470/197218

Answer (score 526, accepted):

In a pure POSIX shell,

```
if [ -t 1 ] ; then echo terminal; else echo "not a terminal"; fi
```

returns "terminal", because the output is sent to your terminal, whereas

```
(if [ -t 1 ] ; then echo terminal; else echo "not a terminal"; fi) | cat
```

returns "not a terminal", because the output of the parenthetic element is piped to `cat`.

---

The `-t` flag is described in man pages as

> -t fd  True if file descriptor fd is open and refers to a terminal.

... where `fd` can be one of the usual file descriptor assignments:

- 0: [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin))
- 1: [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout))
- 2: [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr))

Comment: @Kelvin The man page snippet there suggest that it should, but those file descriptors are not assigned by default.

Comment: To clarify, the `-t` flag is specified in POSIX, and thus should work for any POSIX-compatible shell (that is, it's not a bash extension).  http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/test.html

Comment: Works when running a script as ssh remote command as well. Best answer ever and very simple.

Comment: I agree that after your edit (revision 5), the answer is clearer than in revision 3 and also factually correct (ignoring that “returns” is used very informally where “prints” would be more precise).

Comment: Was looking for a `fish` shell answer.  Using `test` is neat, but I cannot try the parenthesized example as that is not supported.  Tried wrapping it in an analogous `begin; ...; end`, but that did not seem to work, and just ran the positive code block again.  Thought I might need to use `status` but that doesn't seem to check for piping.  I guess I essentially want to check if STDOUT of a preceding command/script is not set to the terminal, thanks to these clarifying answers.

Comment: can we find out path of the input file piped to stdin?

Comment: @linux_newbie this approach doesn't work when invoking `ssh -T`

Comment: @dmckee---ex-moderatorkitten - **but those file descriptors are not assigned by default.**, which file descriptors? `0`, `1`, and `2` are assigned by default for any process.

Comment: can we cheat this using an ENV var? say I want to capture the output via a script, I call this shell command but it detects I'm not in a terminal, so output to be captured ;(

Answer (score 161):

There is no *foolproof* way to determine if STDIN, STDOUT, or STDERR are being piped to/from your script, primarily because of programs like `ssh`.

### Things that "normally" work

For example, the following bash solution works correctly in an interactive shell:

```
[[ -t 1 ]] && \
    echo 'STDOUT is attached to TTY'

[[ -p /dev/stdout ]] && \
    echo 'STDOUT is attached to a pipe'

[[ ! -t 1 && ! -p /dev/stdout ]] && \
    echo 'STDOUT is attached to a redirection'
```

### But they don't always work

However, when executing this command as a non-TTY `ssh` command, STD streams *always* looks like they are being piped.  To demonstrate this, using STDIN because it's easier:

```
# CORRECT: Forced-tty mode correctly reports '1', which represents
# no pipe.
ssh -t localhost '[[ -p /dev/stdin ]]; echo ${?}'

# CORRECT: Issuing a piped command in forced-tty mode correctly
# reports '0', which represents a pipe.
ssh -t localhost 'echo hi | [[ -p /dev/stdin ]]; echo ${?}'

# INCORRECT: Non-tty mode reports '0', which represents a pipe,
# even though one isn't specified here.
ssh -T localhost '[[ -p /dev/stdin ]]; echo ${?}'
```

### Why it matters

This is a pretty big deal, because it implies that there is no way for a bash script to tell whether a non-tty `ssh` command is being piped or not.  Note that this unfortunate behavior was introduced when recent versions of `ssh` started using pipes for non-TTY STDIO.  Prior versions used sockets, which COULD be differentiated from within bash by using `[[ -S ]]`.

### When it matters

This limitation normally causes problems when you want to write a bash script that has behavior similar to a compiled utility, such as `cat`.  For example, `cat` allows the following flexible behavior in handling various input sources simultaneously, and is smart enough to determine whether it is receiving piped input regardless of whether non-TTY or forced-TTY `ssh` is being used:

```
ssh -t localhost 'echo piped | cat - <( echo substituted )'
ssh -T localhost 'echo piped | cat - <( echo substituted )'
```

You can only do something like that if you can reliably determine if pipes are involved or not.  Otherwise, executing a command that reads STDIN when no input is available from either pipes or redirection will result in the script hanging and waiting for STDIN input.

### Other things that don't work

In trying to solve this problem, I've looked at several techniques that fail to solve the problem, including ones that involve:

- examining SSH environment variables
- using `stat` on /dev/stdin file descriptors
- examining interactive mode via `[[ "${-}" =~ 'i' ]]`
- examining tty status via `tty` and `tty -s`
- examining `ssh` status via `[[ "$(ps -o comm= -p $PPID)" =~ 'sshd' ]]`

Note that if you are using an OS that supports the `/proc` virtual filesystem, you might have luck following the symbolic links for STDIO to determine whether a pipe is being used or not.  However, `/proc` is not a cross-platform, POSIX-compatible solution.

I'm extremely interesting in solving this problem, so please let me know if you think of any other technique that might work, preferably POSIX-based solutions that work on both Linux and BSD.

Comment: Clearly inspecting environment variables or process names are very unreliable heuristics. But could you expand a bit why the other heuristics are unfit for this purpose or what their problem is? For example I see no difference in the output of a `stat` call on /dev/stdin. And why does `"${-}"` or `tty -s` not work? I also looked into the source code of `cat` but fail to see which part is doing the magic there that you cannot do in POSIX shell. Could you expand on that?

Comment: @josch I wish I could! I don't presently have time to do a deeper dive into this.  But try any of your suggested approaches with both `ssh -t` and `ssh -T` - you'll see that approaches that work using `ssh -t` don't work using `ssh -T`.

Comment: the `cat..piped...substituted` examples don't seem to produce any observable differences in output, whether run via `ssh -[tT]`, `bash -c`, or directly. And I don't see any TTY-related notes in `man cat`

Comment: And change `-t 1` to `-t 0` if you're worried about STDIN, but not STDOOUT.  :)

Comment: Has anything changed here? Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54668834/799379) answer the solution?

Answer (score 38):

The command [`test`](https://ss64.com/bash/test.html) (builtin in Bash), has an option to check if a file descriptor is a tty.

```
if [ -t 1 ]; then
    # Standard output is a tty
fi
```

See "[`man test`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/test)" or "[`man bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)" and search for "`-t`".

Comment: +1 for "man test" because /usr/bin/test will work even in a shell that doesn't implement -t in its build-in test

Comment: As noted by FireFly in dmckee's answer, a shell which doesn't implement -t doesn't conform to POSIX.

Comment: See also bash's builtin `help test` (and `help help` for more), then `info bash` for more in-depth information. These commands are great if you ever end up scripting offline, or just want to get a broader understanding.

Answer (score 14):

You don't mention which shell you are using, but in Bash, you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -t 1 ]]; then
    # stdout is a terminal
else
    # stdout is not a terminal
fi
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist (if nothing else, link to ***specific*** documentation)? What is Bash-specific? Is some of it dependent on the version of Bash? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/911267/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 8):

On [Solaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_%28operating_system%29), [the suggestion from Dejay Clayton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911168/how-can-i-detect-if-my-shell-script-is-running-through-a-pipe/30520299#30520299) works mostly.  The `-p` does not respond as desired.

File *bash_redir_test.sh* looks like:

```
[[ -t 1 ]] && \
    echo 'STDOUT is attached to TTY'

[[ -p /dev/stdout ]] && \
    echo 'STDOUT is attached to a pipe'

[[ ! -t 1 && ! -p /dev/stdout ]] && \
    echo 'STDOUT is attached to a redirection'
```

On Linux, it works great:

```
:$ ./bash_redir_test.sh
STDOUT is attached to TTY

:$ ./bash_redir_test.sh | xargs echo
STDOUT is attached to a pipe

:$ rm bash_redir_test.log
:$ ./bash_redir_test.sh >> bash_redir_test.log

:$ tail bash_redir_test.log
STDOUT is attached to a redirection
```

On Solaris:

```
:# ./bash_redir_test.sh
STDOUT is attached to TTY

:# ./bash_redir_test.sh | xargs echo
STDOUT is attached to a redirection

:# rm bash_redir_test.log
bash_redir_test.log: No such file or directory

:# ./bash_redir_test.sh >> bash_redir_test.log
:# tail bash_redir_test.log
STDOUT is attached to a redirection

:#
```

Comment: Interesting, I wish I had access to Solaris to test.  If your Solaris instance uses the "/proc" filesystem, there are more reliable solutions that involve searching for "/proc" symbolic links for stdin, stdout, and stderr.

Answer (score 2):

The following code (tested only in Linux Bash 4.4) *should not be considered portable nor recommended*, but for the sake of completeness here it is:

```
ls /proc/$$/fdinfo/* >/dev/null 2>&1 || grep -q 'flags:    00$' /proc/$$/fdinfo/0 && echo "pipe detected"
```

I don't know why, but it seems that file descriptor "3" is somehow created when a Bash function has [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)) piped.