# Detecting the output stream type of a shell script

Tags: linux, unix, shell, scripting

I'm writing a shell script that uses ANSI color characters on the command line.

Example: **example.sh**

```
#!/bin/tcsh
printf "\033[31m Success Color is awesome!\033[0m"
```

My problem is when doing:

```
$ ./example.sh > out
```

or

```
$./example.sh | grep
```

The ASCII codes will be sent out raw along with the text, mucking up the output and just generally causing chaos.

I'm interested to know if there is a way to detect this so I could disable color for this special case.

I've search the tcsh man pages and the web for a while and have not been able to find anything shell specific yet.

I'm not bound to tcsh, it's our group standard... but who cares?

**Is it possible to detect, inside a shell script,  if your output is being redirected or piped?**

Comment: we *just* did this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911168/detect-if-shell-script-is-running-through-a-pipe

Comment: Haha that is kind of really creepy that he asked when I actually was running into the problem. I just got around to actually asking the question.

Comment: A related one: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9957/50602

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See this [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911168/detect-if-shell-script-is-running-through-a-pipe), which covers bash. Tcsh provides the same functionality with `filetest -t 1` to see if standard output is a terminal. If it is, then print the color stuff, else leave it out. Here's tcsh:

```
#!/bin/tcsh
if ( -t 1 ) then
        printf "\033[31m Success Color is awesome!\033[0m"
else
        printf "Plain Text is awesome!"
endif
```

Comment: csh isn't my native language. sorry for the initial goof

Answer (score 7):

Inside a bourne shell script (sh, bask, ksh, ...), you can feed the standard output to the `tty` program (standard in Unix) which tells you whether its input is a tty or not, by using the `-s` flag.

Put the following into "check-tty":

```
    #! /bin/sh
    if tty -s <&1; then
      echo "Output is a tty"
    else
      echo "Output is not a tty"
    fi
```

And try it:

```
    % ./check-tty
    Output is a tty
    % ./check-tty | cat
    Output is not a tty
```

I don't use `tcsh`, but there must be a way to redirect your standard output to `tty`'s standard input. If not, use

```
    sh -c "tty -s <&1"
```

as your test command in your `tcsh` script, check its exit status and you're done.

Comment: sh -c "tty -s <&1" will always return not a tty when being called from inside another script. Great answer though.

Comment: No it won't (and I just tested it).

Answer (score 3):

The detection of the output stream type is covered in the question [detect if shell script is running through a pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911168/detect-if-shell-script-is-running-through-a-pipe/911224#911224).

Having decided that you are talking to terminal, then you can use `tput` to retrieve the correct escape codes for the particular terminal you are using - this will make the code more portable.

An example script (in `bash` I am afraid, as `tcsh` is not my forte) is given below.

```
#!/bin/bash

fg_red=
fg_green=
fg_yellow=
fg_blue=
fg_magenta=
fg_cyan=
fg_white=
bold=
reverse=
attr_end=

if [ -t 1 ]; then
    fg_red=$(tput setaf 1)
    fg_green=$(tput setaf 2)
    fg_yellow=$(tput setaf 3)
    fg_blue=$(tput setaf 4)
    fg_magenta=$(tput setaf 5)
    fg_cyan=$(tput setaf 6)
    fg_white=$(tput setaf 7)
    bold=$(tput bold)
    reverse=$(tput rev)
    underline=$(tput smul)
    attr_end=$(tput sgr0)
fi

echo "This is ${fg_red}red${attr_end}"
echo "This is ${fg_green}green${attr_end}"
echo "This is ${fg_yellow}yellow${attr_end}"
echo "This is ${fg_blue}blue${attr_end}"
echo "This is ${fg_magenta}magenta${attr_end}"
echo "This is ${fg_cyan}cyan${attr_end}"
echo "This is ${fg_white}white${attr_end}"
echo "This is ${bold}bold${attr_end}"
echo "This is ${reverse}reverse${attr_end}"
echo "This is ${underline}underline${attr_end}"
```

For more information see "`man tput`" and "`man terminfo`" - there are all sorts of escape codes to play with.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, there is no way to determine the final destination of the output of your shell script; the only thing you can do is provide a switch which allows for suppression of control characters in the output.