# Detect in C if outputting to a terminal

Tags: c, linux, macos

I'm writing a C program for OS X and Linux, and I want to tweak the output based on whether or not it's going to a terminal. I know we've covered how to do this in a shell script, e.g. here:

[Detecting the output stream type of a shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911816/detecting-the-output-stream-type-of-a-shell-script)

But how do I do it in a C program?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use `isatty()`:

```
$ man isatty
ISATTY(3)                  Linux Programmer's Manual                 ISATTY(3)

NAME
       isatty - does this descriptor refer to a terminal

SYNOPSIS
       #include <unistd.h>

       int isatty(int desc);

DESCRIPTION
       returns  1  if  desc is an open file descriptor connected to a terminal
       and 0 otherwise.
```

Since `stdout` is always file descriptor 1, you can do:

```
if(isatty(1))
    // stdout is a terminal
```

Comment: And could you explain a little bit deeper ? 
What is really checked by this function ?
What really means `connected to a terminal` ?

Comment: @PavelShvechikov It means the file descriptor is associated with a device that is considered to be a terminal. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_terminal_interface

Answer (score 5):

```
if (isatty (1))
    fprintf (stdout, "Outputting to a terminal.");
else
    fprintf (stdout, "Not outputting to a terminal.");
```