# invalid input to the command using echo triggers infinite loop

Tags: unix, echo

I was wondering if there is any way to differentiate whether the input is from stdin or echo command?

i.e.

```
echo 1 | some_command
```

OR

execute `some_command` and it will prompt for the input.

If I enter invalid input in the first case, it leads to infinite loop, screwing all of my error handlings.

It works perfectly fine for 2nd case.

Any ideas?

More output information on the command

```
$ echo -1 | some_command
Invalid Id:
        Id must be positive!
Invalid selection.
Enter valid Id ('d' re-display, 'q' exit):
Invalid Id:
        Id must be positive!
Invalid selection.
Enter valid Id ('d' re-display, 'q' exit):
Invalid Id:
        Id must be positive!
Invalid selection.
Enter valid Id ('d' re-display, 'q' exit):
Invalid Id:
        Id must be positive!
Invalid selection.
Enter valid Id ('d' re-display, 'q' exit):
Invalid Id:
        Id must be positive!
Invalid selection.
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Can you add more of the commands you ran?

Comment: added more information related to the command output on the post.

Comment: Is some_command a script? Which one should be modified?

Comment: yeah I own some_command and I can modify it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `some_command` is a script you own and can change:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ -t 0 ]
then
    # I am being run directly
else
    # I am being piped input from somewhere else
fi
```

See also: [How to detect if my shell script is running through a pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911168/how-to-detect-if-my-shell-script-is-running-through-a-pipe)

In response to your comments, hopefully this gives you some pointers:

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int is_terminal = isatty(0);
    FILE *input = stdin;

    read_input_from(input);

    if (!input_is_valid()) {
        if (!is_terminal) {
            input = fopen("/dev/tty", "r");

            read_input_from(input);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the way. Can I use this in C as well? I mean because my command is a C program executable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061575/detect-in-c-if-outputting-to-a-terminal

Comment: Hi, Thanks, This solves the detection problem. Now, if wrong input is given from pipe, then it goes into infinite loop. So is there any way to change stdin to direct input when input received from pipe is invalid?