# Detect if `cout` outputs to a terminal which accepts colors properly?

Tags: c++, xcode, terminal

**Is there another way than `isatty` to know if `cout` outputs to a terminal which accepts colors properly?**

I'm using [this header](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30304782/2227743) for colors, and I'm already using `if(isatty(1))` to know if the output [goes to a terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1061575/2227743).

Unfortunately when I output colors to Xcode's console I get unescaped sequences - but it works fine when executing the app itself from Terminal.app or iTerm in OS X.

*I suppose that Xcode's console identifies itself as a terminal but still ignores color sequences...*

So I'd like to have a better detection - if possible.

My code itself is trivial, something like this, returning a colored string if `isatty` is true, then it goes to `cout`:

```
std::string Slot::description()
{
    if(isatty(1))
    {
        return FBLU("my_string");
    }
    else
    {
        return "my_string";
    }
}
```

Xcode's output:

[image]

iTerm's output:

[image]

Comment: `isatty` only identifies the output as a terminal of some kind; terminals aren't necessarily in colour. When you're running in XCode, `$TERM` is null, but the more reliable solution is probably to use `ncurses`.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks. It's a good start: maybe I can get $TERM with getenv and then check if null - if it is, I'm in Xcode's console (or any other dumb terminal I guess). I'll try that.

Comment: I did `getenv("TERM")` and got null in XCode, and the configured ones in iTerm and Terminal.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yep, this works, and it answers my question. If you want to post an answer I'll happily accept it. A simple if/else checking if getenv("TERM") is empty tells me if I'm in a dumb terminal, it's perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For XCode specifically, you can check `getenv("TERM")`, as that will return null inside XCode and shouldn't do that if you're running in a "real" terminal.

For a more reliable way to determine whether you have a colour terminal, `ncurses` is probably the way to go.