# Eiffel: is there a way to print colorized characters into a terminal (console)

Tags: linux, colors, terminal, eiffel

Trying to write some logger enhancements I'd like to deal with ANSI codes interpretation, and it seems that it's not working with the standard `io.putstring` method neither with `print` I wonder there is a way to do something such as

`echo -e "\u001B[31mSome_red_txt"` in bash

Seems [other languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2616906/how-do-i-output-coloured-text-to-a-linux-terminal) can do it but I can't in Eiffel.

Answer (score 3):

Using ANSI codes interpretation, you can do

```
print ("%/27/[31mSome_red_txt%N")
print ("%/27/[1;31mbold red text%/27/[0m%N")
```

You may check for existing C libraries like `ncurses`.
Note it will not work on Windows console, as now it does not support ANSI code anymore, so you need to use the Windows API.

Comment: May I suggest you to add some comment about escaping characters with Eiffel which was my error trying to get it working with `\001B`

Answer (score 3):

To complement Jocelyn's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52859933/333007), the same ANSI code sequences can be used on Windows with recent update by making sure the console is initialized to handle the sequences:

```
    -- Make sure the console is allocated in a non-console application.
io.output.end_of_file.do_nothing
    -- Set console to terminal mode.
initialize_terminal
    -- Use ANSI codes to color text.
print ("%/27/[31mSome_red_txt")
```

where

```
initialize_terminal
    external "C inline"
    alias "[
        #ifdef EIF_WINDOWS
            {
                HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
                if (hOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return;
                DWORD dwMode = 0;
                if (!GetConsoleMode(hOut, &dwMode)) return;
                dwMode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
                SetConsoleMode(hOut, dwMode);
            }
        #endif
    ]"
    end
```

After such initialization, `print` statements work the same on Windows and Linux.

If output can go not only to the console, but also to a file, a pipe, etc., error status of setting the terminal mode on Windows console can be recorded in the external feature and used later to avoid outputting ANSI sequences in such cases.

Comment: Based on Alexander's answer. I built quickly a quick and dirty example. See https://gist.github.com/jocelyn/c2a211315898639fc65c3108343a950b  (tested on Windows and Debian)

Comment: What about the case of ssh from MS's windows to Unix or form Unix to MS`s Windows (is that possible)?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor `ssh` uses standard input and output, so there should be no specific issues.

Comment: Expect the program will see that it is running on Unix, and not set up the colour on the MS-Windows terminal. (Does the MS-Windows support any standards, to allow this to happen.)

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor A program that wants to use escape sequences also checks what kind of standard output it is attached to, whether it is a terminal or something else, and uses the escape sequences only when they are supported. For example, the environment variable `TERM` can be used to pass the information about capabilities of the terminal, shells have their own mechanisms to enable colored output, etc.

Comment: @AlexanderKogtenkov Yes you see, my point, and how it needs to be done. However, this is not what your program does. (or am I wrong?)

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor The question is about a possibility to do colored output, when the output is known to go to a terminal. How to detect whether the output indeed goes to a terminal is a different question.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor OK, I missed your point. Indeed, the result of functions `GetConsoleMode` and `SetConsoleMode` can be used to see whether terminal facilities (such as colored output) are supported by the associated output stream on Windows. Similar functionality [exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061575/detect-in-c-if-outputting-to-a-terminal) on Linux. Some other means should be used to do it when output generated on one machine is to be displayed on another.

Comment: You will never know what machine it is displayed on until run time. So you need to write code to do that. I know it can be done, on Unixes. But don't know about MS, or the cmd terminal.