# How can I tell if my script is being run from a cronjob or from the command line?

Tags: python, cron

I have a script and it's display show's upload progress by writing to the same console line. When the script is run from a cron job, rather than writing to a single line, I get many lines:

```
***   E0710091001.DAT  ***   [0.67%]
***   E0710091001.DAT  ***   [1.33%]
***   E0710091001.DAT  ***   [2.00%]
***   E0710091001.DAT  ***   [2.66%]
***   E0710091001.DAT  ***   [3.33%]
***   E0710091001.DAT  ***   [3.99%]
***   E0710091001.DAT  ***   [4.66%]
***   E0710091001.DAT  ***   [5.32%]
***   E0710091001.DAT  ***   [5.99%]
***   E0710091001.DAT  ***   [6.65%]
***   E0710091001.DAT  ***   [7.32%]
***   E0710091001.DAT  ***   [7.98%]
***   E0710091001.DAT  ***   [8.65%]
***   E0710091001.DAT  ***   [9.32%]
***   E0710091001.DAT  ***   [9.98%]
***   E0710091001.DAT  ***   [10.65%]
***   E0710091001.DAT  ***   [11.31%]
***   E0710091001.DAT  ***   [11.98%]
***   E0710091001.DAT  ***   [12.64%]
***   E0710091001.DAT  ***   [13.31%]
***   E0710091001.DAT  ***   [13.97%]
***   E0710091001.DAT  ***   [14.64%]
***   E0710091001.DAT  ***   [15.30%]
***   E0710091001.DAT  ***   [15.97%]
***   E0710091001.DAT  ***   [16.63%]
***   E0710091001.DAT  ***   [17.30%]
***   E0710091001.DAT  ***   [17.97%]
***   E0710091001.DAT  ***   [18.63%]
```

I just want to know if I can tell from inside the script if it's being called from cron, and if so, I won't display this output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See code below.  Replace my print statements with what you want to show.

```
import sys
if sys.stdout.isatty():
    print "Running from command line"
else:
    print "Running from cron"
```

Comment: will this confuse processes run by applications other than cron with cron jobs?

Comment: Technically what this actually does is check to see if stdout is attached to a terminal or not.  Redirected to a file for instance, which is what cron will do.  Given that the OP's question was about determining what to print, I guessed that it is a safe assumption that printing behavior when redirecting to a file is the same regardless of whether it is initiated by cron or not.

Answer (score 10):

you could create a flag. Possibly undocumented that your cron job would pass to the utility to structure the output.

Comment: No worries, happens to us all.  Glad I could help.

Comment: This solution is expedient, but the right solution is to check for a tty/terminal

Comment: I would prefer to not have the argument, so I've accepted another answer. Thanks, though!

Comment: Document the flag. What if in the future you want this functionality adapted for another method of the script being called? A person could easily see the "--iscron   Format the output safely for logging when called by cron" and just move on.

Answer (score 10):

I'd check `sys.stderr.isatty()` -- this way you avoid useless "decoration" output to stderr whenever it wouldn't be immediately perceptible by the user anyway.

Answer (score 6):

You want to check if you're on a terminal or not.  See this stack overflow question:
[How to detect if my shell script is running through a pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911168/detect-if-shell-script-is-running-through-a-pipe)

Answer (score 2):

An easy way would be to have the script take an argument that means to suppress that output, and supply that argument when you call it from cron.