# Can a bash script tell if it's being run via cron?

Tags: bash, cron

Not having much luck Googling this question and I thought about posting it on SF, but it actually seems like a development question. If not, please feel free to migrate.

So, I have a script that runs via cron every morning at about 3 am. I also run the same scripts manually sometimes. The problem is that every time I run my script manually and it fails, it sends me an e-mail; even though I can look at the output and view the error in the console.

Is there a way for the bash script to tell that it's being run through cron (perhaps by using whoami) and only send the e-mail if so? I'd love to stop receiving emails when I'm doing my testing...

Comment: Are you emailing from within your script? Doesn't cron by default mail output to the owner of the crontab?

Comment: I am e-mailing from within, but I needed to send the output. I didn't realize that cron did this.

Comment: Hey be using ACTUAL outgoing email as in 'mail', not just using the unix mail system.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you can try "tty" to see if it's run by a terminal or not. that won't tell you that it's specifically run by cron, but you can tell if its "not a user as a prompt".

you can also get your parent-pid and follow it up the tree to look for cron, though that's a little heavy-handed.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! The former answer I picked was actually not what I wanted (interactive shell). Due to your answer, I found what I really needed by Googling "bash tty test". Basically, call `tty -s` in your script and then check `$?`: if it is 0, you are in a tty, if it's greater than 0, you aren't.

Comment: `tty` is an external command (granted part of coreutils, but still a fork), there are several ways to use builtin stuff to do the same described at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46801/103306

Answer (score 19):

I had a similar issue. I solved it with checking if stdout was a TTY. This is a check to see if you script runs in interactive mode:

```
if [ -t 1 ] ; then 
    echo "interacive mode";
else
    #send mail
fi
```

I got this from: [How to detect if my shell script is running through a pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911168/how-to-detect-if-my-shell-script-is-running-through-a-pipe)

The -t test return true if file descriptor is open and refers to a terminal. '1' is stdout.

Answer (score 11):

Here's two different options for you:

- Take the emailing out of your script/program and let cron handle it. If you set the MAILTO variable in your crontab, cron will send anything printed out to that email address. eg:

  ```
  MAILTO=youremail@example.com
  # run five minutes after midnight, every day
  5 0 * * *       $HOME/bin/daily.job
  ```
- Set an environment variable in your crontab that is used to determine if running under cron. eg:

  ```
  THIS_IS_CRON=1
  # run five minutes after midnight, every day
  5 0 * * *       $HOME/bin/daily.job
  ```

  and in your script something like

  ```
  if [ -n "$THIS_IS_CRON" ]; then echo "I'm running in cron"; else echo "I'm not running in cron"; fi
  ```

Answer (score 10):

Why not have a command line argument that is -t for testing or -c for cron.

Or better yet:

-e=email@address.com

If it's not specified, don't send an email.

Comment: I'm dropping the script in /etc/cron.daily so I can't easily add arguments, but I guess I could move it to a real crontab. I was just hoping not to have to add arguments or set environment variables on the command line...although: setting a TESTING environment variable in my .bashrc file would do the trick.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: There is no problem with putting myscript.sh arg1 arg2 arg3 in a script file in /etc/cron.daily. I don't usually put my script/binary file directly into the /etc/cron.* dirs. I usually leave that for scripts that execute the cron job (may be another script). Then I can write my script more generic and usable in other environments.

Answer (score 8):

I know the question is old, but I just came across the same problem. This was my solution:

```
CRON=$(pstree -s $$ | grep -q cron && echo true || echo false)
```

then test with

```
if $CRON
then
    echo "Being run by cron"
else
    echo "Not being run by cron"
fi
```

same idea as the one that @eruciform mentioned - follows your PID up the process tree checking for cron.

Note: This solution only works specifically for cron, unlike some of the other solutions, which work anytime the script is being run non-interactively.

Comment: I love the simplicity of setting the var to true or false (commands) so that if $CRON works (as opposed to the usual if [ "$CRON" ]), but note that if $CRON ends up undefined for some reason, the given version evaluates as true.  Not good.

Comment: I also liked the idea, but also see the risk of having undefined returns. I ended up with a slightly modified version, which seems to work very smooth in my opinion:

CRON="$( pstree -s $$ | grep -c cron )"

So you can check if $CRON is 1 or 0.

Answer (score 5):

What works for me is to check `$TERM`.  Under cron it's "dumb" but under a shell it's something else.  Use the `set` command in your terminal, then in a cron-script and check it out

```
if [ "dumb" == "$TERM" ]
then
    echo "cron"
else
    echo "term"
fi
```

Comment: I would also check if $TERM is not empty.
`[ -n "$TERM" -a "$TERM" == "dumb" ] && echo "interactive" || echo "cron or no tty"`

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to suggest a new answer to this highly-voted question.  This works only on systemd systems with [`loginctl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/loginctl.html) (e.g. Ubuntu 14.10+, RHEL/CentOS 7+) but is able to give a much more authoritative answer than previously presented solutions.

```bash
if [[ $(loginctl show-session -P Service '') == 'crond' ]]; then
   echo "running in cron"
fi
```

---

To summarize: when used with systemd, `crond` (like `sshd` and others) creates a new [session](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/pam_systemd.html#Description) when it starts a job for a user.  This session has an ID that is unique for the entire uptime of the machine.  Each session has some properties, one of which is the name of the service that started it.  `loginctl` can tell us the value of this property, which will be "`crond`" *if and only if* the session was actually started by crond.

---

Advantages over using environment variables:

- No need to modify cron entries to add special invocations or environment variables
- No possibility of an intermediate process modifying environment variables to create a false positive or false negative

Advantages over testing for tty:

- No false positives in pipelines, startup scripts, etc

Advantages over checking the process tree:

- No false positives from processes that also have `crond` in their name
- No false negatives if the script is disowned

Comment: Shame that like other systemd commands it is very long winded and very non-obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Many of the commands used in prior posts are not available on every system (pstree, loginctl, tty). This was the only thing that worked for me on a ten years old BusyBox/OpenWrt router that I'm currently using as a blacklist DNS server. It runs a script with an auto-update feature. Running from crontab, it sends an email out.

```
[ -z "$TERM" ] || [ "$TERM" = "dumb" ] && echo 'Crontab' || echo 'Interactive'
```

In an interactive shell the `$TERM`-variable returns the value `vt102` for me. I included the check for "dumb" since @edoceo mentioned it worked for him. I didn't use '==' since it's not completely portable.

Answer (score 0):

I also liked the idea from Tal, but also see the risk of having undefined returns. I ended up with a slightly modified version, which seems to work very smooth in my opinion:

`CRON="$( pstree -s $$ | grep -c cron )"`

So you can check for $CRON being 1 or 0 at any time.