# Can a Bash function in pipe knows anything about the next function after it?

Tags: bash, pipe

Can `command_b` knows that `command_c` is following?

> command_a | command_b | command_c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other answerers said, no, `command_b` cannot (need not, should not) know that `command_c` follows. I'm adding another answer because here is a little additional information:

1. The shell interpreter (Bash, in this case) *does*, and *must* know (because it implements the pipe).
2. A program can tell if its standard output is to a terminal. This can be used to change behavior on the fly (for instance, `command_b` might omit ASCII color codes, while `command_c` might colorize its output).

See also:

- [the `isatty(3)` manpage](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/isatty.3.html)
- [How to detect if my shell script is running through a pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911168/detect-if-shell-script-is-running-through-a-pipe)
- [Test whether the actual output is a terminal or not in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080458/test-whether-the-actual-output-is-a-terminal-or-not-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

No. Each program is just reading standard input and writing to standard output.

Answer (score 0):

No, it cannot, need not and should not.