# Shell script pipeline: different behavior with or without xclip

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, pipeline

I have a script named `password-for-object` which I normally run like that:

```
$ password-for-object example.com
sOtzC0UY1K3EDYp8a6ltfA
```

I.e. it does an intricate hash calculation and outputs a password that I should use when accessing an object (for example, website) named `example.com`. I'll just double click the whole password, it gets copied into my buffer and I'll paste it into the form.

I've also learnt a trick on how to use such a script without making my password visible:

```
$ password-for-object example.com | xclip
```

This way output of a script ends up in X's primary buffer and I can insert it right into password field in the form and it's not shown on the screen.

The only problem with this way is that `password-for-object` outputs a string with trailing newline and thus "xclip" always catches up an extra symbol - this newline. If I omit output of newline in `password-for-object`, then I'll end up with messed up string without xclip, i.e. when I'm just putting it on the stdout. I use 2 shells: zsh and bash, and I'll get the following in zsh (note the extra % sign):

```
$ password-for-object example.com
sOtzC0UY1K3EDYp8a6ltfA%
$
```

Or the following in bash (note that prompt would be started on the same line):

```
$ password-for-object example.com
sOtzC0UY1K3EDYp8a6ltfA$
```

Any ideas on how to work around this issue? Is it possible to modify the script in a way so it will detect that xclip is in the pipeline and only output newline if it isn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change `password-for-object` so that it doesn't output a newline, you can call it with a script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
password-for-object "$1"
if [ -t 1 ]
then
    echo
fi
```

The `-t` condition is described in [the bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) as:

> *-t fd*
>
> True if file descriptor fd is open and refers to a terminal.

See the following question:

- [How to detect if my shell script is running through a pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911168/detect-if-shell-script-is-running-through-a-pipe)

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
$ password-for-object example.com | tr -d '\n' | xclip
```

tr -d '\n' deletes the newline

Comment: That's not very comfortable to write every time. Rolling my own wrapper over xclip (i.e. `myxclip` = `td -d '\n' | xclip`) is possible, but also not very comfortable: it would be one extra script to distribute across the every system that I use.