# How does grep make the color?

Tags: linux, bash, redirect, colors, grep

I know in bash I can print a colorful string, like:

```
echo -e "\033[33;1mhello\033[0m"
```

The output in a shell will be **`hello`** with golden color. But when I redirect the output to a file `test.txt`, the `\033[33;` will be in the text file too. However the `grep --color=auto` command won't redirect these characters into the text file. How can it do this?

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911168/how-to-detect-if-my-shell-script-is-running-through-a-pipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably uses the [isatty(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) library function on stdout file descriptor (i.e. 1). So use

```
if (isatty(STDOUT_FILENO)) {
   // enable auto colorization
}
```

in your C code.

In a shell script, use the [tty(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tty.1.html) command:

```
if tty -s ; then
  # enable auto colorization
fi
```

or simply the `-t` [test(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html)

```
if [ -t 1 ]; then
  # enable auto colorization
fi
```

Comment: There are various scripts for removing color codes and all kinds of control chars, e.g. the one from this [question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/removing-control-chars-including-console-codes-colours-from-script-output).

Comment: Thanks. I see. But that perl script doesn't work at least for Chinese words. The sed version may be better: http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3584/remove-color-codes-special-characters-with-sed

Comment: The `--always` option should take an argument like "always" to force color regardless of the output destination.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -t 1 ]; then
    echo -e "\033[33;1mhello\033[0m"
else
    echo hello
fi
```

Here the explanation:

`test -t <fd>`, whose short form is `[ -t <fd> ]`, checks if the descriptor `<fd>` is a terminal or not. Source: `help test`

Answer (score 0):

Use the the GREP_COLORS variable with an export flag. Tested this and it works:

```
export GREP_COLORS='ms=01;33'
grep --color=auto -e hello
```