# Detect if stdout is redirected to a pipe (not to a file, character device, terminal, or socket)?

Tags: linux, unix, posix, sh

Ideally, this would be scriptable in shell, but Perl or Python would be fine.
C code could be helpful, but probably fails cost/benefit.

I recognize that redirection to a FIFO (named pipe) may be indistinguishable from a real pipe,
and that is enough of an edge case that I don't really care.

Strict POSIX solutions are best, UNIX/Linux variant-independent are next best, but at least something that works on Darwin (MacOS X) is what I need right now.

Before you write your answer - [**I already know about `test -t`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911168/how-to-detect-if-my-shell-script-is-running-through-a-pipe/911224#911224) - that will tell me whether stdout is a terminal (in which case it is definitely not a pipe - but it will not tell me whether stdout has been redirected to a file, non-terminal character device, or UNIX-domain socket rather than a pipe.

Intended use case: I have a command that should be run within backquotes in the shell,
so that it can output commands that set environment variables.
I would like the command to abort with an error if stdout is not redirected to a pipe,
as in that case it definitely wasn't invoked by `` eval `mycommand`; ``.

If there's some special environment variable that a shell will set when running a command within backquotes that would be helpful, but as it is likely to be specific to bash or zsh or something, pipe-detection is more important.

Comment: I wouldn't technically enforce this, I'd just output whatever it needs to be eval'ed and expect the coder/user knows how to use my script properly (using eval) because they read my script documentation (RTFM, right?). But anyways, good question and I hope you get the proper technical answer.

Comment: Generally, I'd agree with you, @KurzedMetal, but for MacOS X, getting users to even type something in at the Terminal is scary - properly understanding eval backquotes and such is a black art, they would have no idea that anything was actually wrong.

Comment: Since you said you can use perl, I guess you can use its `-p` file test operator (http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html); something like `perl -e 'exit(-p STDOUT ? 0 : 1);'` will tell you if stdout if a pipe or a fifo (without distinguishing between them).

Comment: @loreb - that Perl test is good and quite short enough to use even in a shell script (I'd simplify it a bit to ``perl -e 'exit ! -p STDOUT'``).  You should put this as an answer, probably the best so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(my comment turned to answer per Alex Dupuy's suggestion)
Since you said you can use perl, I guess you can use its -p file test operator ([perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)); something like `perl -e 'exit(-p STDOUT ? 0 : 1);'` will tell you if stdout if a pipe or a fifo (**without** distinguishing between them).

Fwiw, calling that from the shell is exactly the reason why I used `perl -e` :)

Answer (score 4):

You could do an [`fstat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) to the file descriptor and check returning structure, for example, `st_mode` = 0x1000 (S_IFIFO) indicates a Named Pipe.

Example with Python:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
import os

print(os.fstat(sys.stdout.fileno()), file=sys.stderr)
```

Output on windows:

```
C:> python test_fd.py | more
nt.stat_result(st_mode=4096, st_ino=0L, st_dev=0, st_nlink=0, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=0L, st_atime=0L, st_mtime=0L, st_ctime=0L)

C:> python test_fd.py > test_fd.txt
nt.stat_result(st_mode=33206, st_ino=16888498602769633L, st_dev=0, st_nlink=1, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=0L, st_atime= 1401119520L, st_mtime=1401119520L, st_ctime=1401119349L)
```

Comment: Yes, the ``st_mode`` bit ``S_IFIFO`` (010000 octal = 4096 decimal) does the trick, and by checking for ``st_ino == 0`` you can eliminate redirection to named pipes as well.  With a bit of tuning this is probably a better solution than my use of ``/usr/bin/stat`` because it is more portable (only depends on POSIX features of a common scripting language rather than a Unix/Linux-centric utility that may not be present on many distributions, and likely never on Windows).

Comment: Looking at the `fstat` system call documentation I found out there's a macro defined to check Pipes: [S_ISFIFO, which is included in the Python `stat` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stat.html#stat.S_ISFIFO) too. Although checking other stats/flags may be helpful too.

Answer (score 2):

In Python:

```
import sys
print sys.stdout.isatty()
```

Examples:

```
$ ./a
True
$ ./a | less
False
```

Answer (score 1):

The `stat` command works on MacOS X and (with some finessing of variant implementations) other Linux/Unix variants as well, so it is a solution for me:

```
FORMOPT=
TYPEFORM=
stat() {
  if [ -z "$FORMOPT" ]; then
    if /usr/bin/stat --version >/dev/null 2>&1; then
      FORMOPT=--format
      TYPEFORM=%F
    else
      FORMOPT=-f
      TYPEFORM=%HT
    fi
  fi
  case $1 in
    type) FORMARG="$FORMOPT $TYPEFORM" ; shift ;;
  esac
  /usr/bin/stat -L $FORMARG "$@"
}

exec 9>&1
case `stat type /dev/fd/9` in
  [Ff]ifo*) echo stdout is a pipe ;;
  *) echo stdout is not a pipe ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

There *is* a Linux-specific solution that does what I want:

```
exec 9>&1
case `readlink /dev/fd/9` in
    pipe:\[*\]) echo stdout is a pipe ;;
    *) echo stdout is not a pipe ;;
esac
```

but that isn't the answer I am looking for as I want this to run on xBSD as well.

I've made this answer community wiki, so feel free to improve it,
but if you have a non-Linux solution (or a Linux-specific solution using another technique),
please create a new answer.