# How to detect fully interactive shell in bash from docker?

Tags: bash, docker

I'm wanting to detect in "docker run" whether -ti has been passed to the entrypoint script.

docker run --help for -t -i

```
-i, --interactive=false     Keep STDIN open even if not attached
-t, --tty=false             Allocate a pseudo-TTY
```

I have tried the following but even when tested locally (not inside docker) it didn't work and printed out "Not interactive" always.

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ $- == *i* ]] && echo 'Interactive' || echo 'Not interactive'
```

Comment: If you just have it echo `$-` what do you get?  Also, what version of bash are you running?

Comment: Oddy enough, that should work.  I think -t would do.

Comment: A script run as a script (`/path/to/script` or `bash /path/to/script`) isn't run in interactive mode. Run that command at your shell prompt or source it (`. /path/to/script`) and it will work the way you expect.

Comment: Thanks.  Nevermind.  I found out  I can detect tty with the test -t option.  I can't tell if -i was specifid but -t will at least tell me if there is a tty and if that fails I can instruct to rerun with -ti

Comment: Not sure why the downvote, but I have clarified it's the entrypoint script I'm wanting to detect this in.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

if [ -t 0 ] ; then
    echo "(interactive shell)"
else
    echo "(not interactive shell)"
fi
/bin/bash -c "$@"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:7.8

COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 755 /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

build the image:

```
$ docker build -t is_interactive .
```

run the image interactively:

```
$ docker run -ti --rm is_interactive "/bin/bash"
(interactive shell)
root@dd7dd9bf3f4e:/$ echo something
something
root@dd7dd9bf3f4e:/$ echo $HOME
/root
root@dd7dd9bf3f4e:/$ exit
exit
```

run the image not interactively:

```
$ docker run --rm is_interactive "echo \$HOME"
(not interactive shell)
/root
$
```

This [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911168/how-to-detect-if-my-shell-script-is-running-through-a-pipe) helped me find `[ -t 0 ]`.

Comment: From my testing this will tell you whether the `-t` option has been passed, but tell you nothing about whether `-i` was passed.

Comment: You also need the `[ -t 1 ]` to detect interactive mode. The `--tty` option in docker run just tells docker to allocate a tty, but doesn't mean you get a shell. So for completeness, you need something like `[[ -t 0 && -t 1 ]]` to ensure that even if the image is run with a tty, but the `--detach` option is passed, you can still detect that this is a non-interactive session, and do something appropriate

Comment: @smac89 on my tests, passing `--tty` is enough to make test -t 0 and test -t 1 pass. So I think it does not make any difference.