# Check if program is being piped

Tags: c, git, pipe

I'm writing a program that speeds up the `git push` operation. Here's what it needs to do:

```
printf("[github-username]\n[github-password]");
```

I'd then use it like so:

```
git-autologin | git push
```

But I don't want there to be any chance of someone simply typing `git-autologin` or `git-autologin > file.txt` and being able to see my username and password. I know it sounds silly 'cause anyone can still automate the git commands but it's unlikely that any untrusted user will ever get on my system.

**My question:** How could I tell if standard output is writing to a file/terminal or if it's being piped?
**Edit:** The `git push` pipe was simply an idea, not the only reason I'm asking.
**Edit:** Is there any way to determine the PID or more information about the process it's being piped to?

Comment: BTW if the 'git' tag needs to be removed please feel free to remove it, or comment.

Comment: For this particular solution you may want to read up on [git credentials helpers](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials).  Actually, you would better off just using an ssh key for authentication, rather than a username/password.

Comment: @larsks Thanks, I'll look into that but this isn't the only reason I'm asking, just the most explainable one

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911168/how-to-detect-if-my-shell-script-is-running-through-a-pipe) isn't exactly a duplicate, because it's shell rather than C, but I think it provides the general answer (which is, you can't really do what you want).

Comment: `git-autologin | cat`. Now what.

Comment: You can't seek on a pipe or terminal; you can on files.  You can tell if a device is a terminal by looking at the type information (`stat()` on the output file descriptor and `S_ISCHR` macro, or maybe check for `S_ISREG`); if it looks looks like a regular file, (`S_ISREG`), but you can't seek on it (`errno == ESPIPE` after an attempt to seek), it is probably a pipe.  You can't tell if the command on the receiving end is `cat` very easily, though.

Comment: This is silly. All someone has to do is run `strings git-autologin` and they'll see your credentials.

Comment: The literal answer is the `isatty` function (this is what libc uses internally to choose stdout buffering), but as already noted, `git-autologin | cat` makes this a bad idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can detect when *stdout* is a *terminal* by using (on Linux & POSIX!) the [isatty(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) function, probably as `isatty(STDOUT_FILENO)`

So you could guess that if `isatty(STDOUT_FILENO)`  is false, the standard output is would be redirected or piped.

Alternatively, use [fstat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fstat.2.html) as `fstat(STDOUT_FILENO, &stdoutstat);`

But you should set up `ssh` correctly (with credentials, STFW for any SSH tutorial!) on your system, to avoid having `git` asking any password.