# How to detect if a Ruby script is running through a shell pipe?

Tags: ruby, shell, pipe

My question is similar to this one: [How to detect if my shell script is running through a pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911168/how-to-detect-if-my-shell-script-is-running-through-a-pipe). The difference is that the script I’m working on is written in Ruby.

Let’s say I run:

```
./test.rb
```

I expect text on stdout with color, but

```
./test.rb | cat
```

I expect the color codes to be stripped out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `$stdout.isatty` or more idiomatically, `$stdout.tty?`. I created a little test.rb file to demonstrate, contents:

```
puts $stdout.isatty
```

Results:

```
$ ruby test.rb
true

$ ruby test.rb | cat
false
```

Reference: https://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-isatty

Comment: or more idiomatic: `$stdout.tty?`

Answer (score 5):

Use `IO#stat.pipe?`.
`IO#tty?` returns true *only* on a TTY device.
Returns false for UNIX-style pipes (see "man 2 pipe").

```
 $ echo "something" | ruby -e 'puts $stdin.stat.pipe?'
true
 $ echo "something" | ruby -e 'puts $stdin.tty?'
false
 $ ruby -e 'puts $stdin.tty?'
true
```