# Detect if a command is piped or not

Tags: go, pipe

Is there a way to detect if a command in go is piped or not?

Example:

```
cat test.txt | mygocommand #Piped, this is how it should be used
mygocommand # Not piped, this should be blocked
```

I'm reading from the Stdin `reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)`.

Comment: Why do you want to block that? Is it actually a *problem* if someone types the input into their terminal manually, or maybe copy-pastes it or something?

Comment: Maybe you've seen this already, but here's a parallel line of questioning for shell scripts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911168/how-to-detect-if-my-shell-script-is-running-through-a-pipe

Comment: @user2357112 The users input will never end, because there won't be an EOF, will it?

Comment: @Florian: Ctrl-D, or Ctrl-Z Enter at the beginning of a line on Windows.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `os.Stdin.Stat()`.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "os"
)

func main() {
    fi, _ := os.Stdin.Stat()

    if (fi.Mode() & os.ModeCharDevice) == 0 {
        fmt.Println("data is from pipe")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("data is from terminal")
    }
}
```

(Adapted from [this tutorial](https://www.socketloop.com/tutorials/golang-check-if-os-stdin-input-data-is-piped-or-from-terminal))

Answer (score 2):

same can be done with performing a similar bitwise operation with ModeNamedPipe

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "os"
)

func main() {
        fi, err := os.Stdin.Stat()
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }

        if (fi.Mode() & os.ModeNamedPipe) != 0 {
                fmt.Println("data is from pipe")
        } else {
                fmt.Println("data is from terminal")
        }
}
```