# How does a program like less handle both piped stdin and keyboard input?

Tags: unix, process, pipe, stdin, less-unix

If I run, for example, `ifconfig | less`, the `less` program manages to at the same time:

1. Capture output of `ifconfig` through the standard input where the output of `ifconfig` is piped
2. React to user's keyboard input and be interactive

I never gave this much thought, but as I tried to write a program with functionality similar to less, I got confused: how does it manage to do both at the same time, and what does it do to implement 2, as it's clearly not the standard input?

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43947363/detect-if-a-command-is-piped-or-not) for a solution in Go. It will be similar in other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It reads keyboard input from `/dev/tty` instead of from stdin.