# How to detect when a bash script is triggered from keybinding

Tags: linux, bash, shell, i3

#### Background

I have a Bash script that requires user input. It can be run by calling it in a terminal *or* by pressing a keyboard shortcut registered in the i3 (or Sway) config file as follows:

```
bindsym --release $mod+Shift+t exec /usr/local/bin/myscript
```

#### The Problem

I know I can use `read -p` to prompt in a terminal, but that obviously won't work when the script is triggered through the keybinding. In that case I can use something like [Yad](https://github.com/v1cont/yad) to create a GUI, but I'm unable to detect when it's not "in a terminal". Essentially I want to be able to do something like this:

```sh
if [ $isInTerminal ]; then
    read -rp "Enter your username: " username
else
    username=$(yad --entry --text "Enter your username:")
fi
```

**How can I (automatically) check if my script was called from the keybinding, or is running in a terminal?** Ideally this should be *without* user-specified command-line arguments. Others may use the script and as such, I'd like to avoid introducing any possibility of user error via "forgotten flags".

---

#### Attempted "Solution"

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911168/how-to-detect-if-my-shell-script-is-running-through-a-pipe) suggests checking if `stdout` is going to a terminal, so I created this test script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

rm -f /tmp/detect.log

logpass() {
    echo "$1 IS opened on a terminal" >> /tmp/detect.log
}
logfail() {
    echo "$1 IS NOT opened on a terminal" >> /tmp/detect.log
}

if [ -t 0 ]; then logpass stdin; else logfail stdin; fi
if [ -t 1 ]; then logpass stdout; else logfail stdout; fi
if [ -t 2 ]; then logpass stderr; else logfail stderr; fi
```

However, this doesn't solve my problem. Regardless of whether I run `./detect.sh` in a terminal or trigger it via keybind, output is always the same:

```sh
$ cat /tmp/detect.log
stdin IS opened on a terminal
stdout IS opened on a terminal
stderr IS opened on a terminal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### False Positive

As most results on Google would suggest, you *could* use `tty` which would normally return *"not a tty"* when it's not running in a terminal. However, this seems to differ with scripts called via `bindsym exec` in i3/Sway:

```
/dev/tty1  # From a keybind
/dev/pts/6 # In a terminal
/dev/tty2  # In a console
```

While `tty | grep pts` would go part way to answering the question, it is unable to distinguish between running in a console vs from a keybinding which you won't want if you're trying to show a GUI.

---

#### "Sort of" Solution

Triggering via keybinding seems to always have `systemd` as the parent process. With that in mind, something like this *could* work:

```
{
    [ "$PPID" = "1" ] && echo "keybind" || echo "terminal"
} > /tmp/detect.log
```

It is likely a safe assumption that the `systemd` process will always have `1` as its PID, but there's no guarantee that every system using i3 will also be using systemd so this is probably best avoided.

---

#### Better Solution

A more robust way would be using `ps`. According to `PROCESS STATE CODES` in the man page:

> For BSD formats and when the stat keyword is used, additional characters may be displayed:
>
> ```
> <    high-priority (not nice to other users)
> N    low-priority (nice to other users)
> L    has pages locked into memory (for real-time and custom IO)
> s    is a session leader
> l    is multi-threaded (using CLONE_THREAD, like NPTL pthreads do)
> +    is in the foreground process group
> ```

The key here is `+` on the last line. To check that in a terminal you can call `ps -Sp <PID>` which will have a `STAT` value of `Ss` when running "interactively", or `S+` if it's triggered via keybinding.

Since you only need the `STATE` column, you can further clean that up with `-o stat=` which will also remove the headers, then pipe through grep to give you the following:

```sh
is_interactive() {
    ps -o stat= -p $$ | grep -q '+'
}

if is_interactive; then
    read -rp "Enter your username: " username
else
    username=$(yad --entry --text "Enter your username:")
fi
```

This will work not only in a terminal emulator and via an i3/Sway keybinding, but even in a raw console window, making it a much more reliable option than `tty` above.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the easiest way to solve your actual problem would be to change the i3 bind to

```
bindsym --release $mod+Shift+t exec /usr/local/bin/myscript fromI3
```

and do

```
if [[ -n "$1" ]]; then
    echo "this was from a keybind"
else
    echo "this wasn't from a keybind"
fi
```

in your script.

Answer (score 0):

I use `-t` to check if stdin (file descriptor 0) is attached to a terminal.  I may be off the mark here, but I use it in my own scripts that way, and this small test works as expected

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -t 0 ]; then
    echo "A terminal!"
else
    zenity --info --text "not a terminal"
fi
```