# Is there a human readable structured logging fomat?

Tags: json, logging, api-design, human-readable, structured-logging

I'd like my program to write to its stderr a log that is simultaneously human and machine readable.

Requirements:

1. A log is a stream of messages. I.e. I can't write just one big xml or json document. Every message has to be parseable separately without requiring an incremental parser or generator.
2. [tty detection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/911168) and log format selection switches are considered cheating for the purposes of this question. I want the same exact output to be simultaneously human and machine readable.
3. No postprocessing for the same reasons as 2
4. No ad hoc formats. I don't want the consumer to have to write a parser. Not even a trivial one.
5. No formats that are too obscure. There must be a library to parse this format in the top 10 most popular general purpose programming languages **and** the library must be able to parse the entire log into a stream of messages **out of the box** without requiring the consumer to massage the data.

- Pretty JSON fails 5 - most JSON parsing APIs cannot parse multiple concatenated JSON documents.
- [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/) is not human readable especially if it contains nested data because the entire log entry ends up on a single line.
- It appears that [application/json-seq (RFC 7464)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7464) does allow for the JSON texts to be pretty printed (human readable) while only requiring very simple parsing on top of a regular JSON decoder. This is the closest one yet.

## Post-mortem

I ended up rethinking my approach: log [jsonlines](https://jsonlines.org) - easiest to generate and consume, post-process with en external pretty-printer such as [`jq .`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for human consumption.

Comment: Is the target a Unix terminal? If so, it's pretty simple and nice to use VT100 ANSI escape sequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) seems to be a fine choice.
You can emit the log as stand-alone YAML documents, separated by `---`[1].
Having multiple documents is standard YAML and this is at least supported by the YAML parser I know about. Basic structured data can be printed in one line in YAML, while still being pretty human readable.

https://yaml.org/ has a list of implementations for different programming languages. There is an implementation for all the top ten programming languages in the [stackoverflow 2021 developer survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2021#most-popular-technologies-language)[2].

### Example Log

```yaml
{level: INFO, message: first log message, time: "2021-10-06 21:37", data: [item1, item2, item3]}
---  # document separator (and this is a comment btw)
{level: INFO, message: still logging, time: "2021-10-06 21:38", data: {key1: [nested, data], key2: whatever}}
---
{level: FATAL, message: getting bored, time: "2021-10-06 21:38", data: 0}
```

[1] ok, that means you have to emit `---` every second line or you have to insert it before parsing the document between all lines. If you just emit a `---` in every second line, YAML satisfies your fifth requirement.
[2] except for Kotlin, but Kotlin users may use the java library as far as I can see

Answer (score 2):

**LIFECYCLE**

Logging needs to be understood as a lifecycle, where JSON logs are typically used in 2 formats:

- On a developer PC you use prettified output
- In deployed systems you use a log entry per line bare format that suits log shippers such as Filebeat
- Logs are then aggregated from the bare format to a system where they are used by humans in a readable way

The production logs remain human readable - tools such as Kibana allow you to view them in a readable format and ask questions of them.

When you think about the above flow it makes sense, since log storage is efficient and readability is also good. It requires a separation of concerns though.

**ONLINE DEMO LOGGING SYSTEM**

Feel free to log in to my cloud Elastic Search system at the bottom of [this page](https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart/). Log in to my web app at the top of the page, then query your own API activity in Kibana [like this](https://authguidance.com/2019/08/02/intelligent-api-platform-analysis/).

My system is a logging design for a microservices platform - see my [Effective API Logging](https://authguidance.com/2019/03/24/effective-api-logging/) blog post in case interested in how it works. A good logging system usually needs an architectural design like this.